# MS Blazor assign value from a page to another page

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I'm creating a simple web by using MS Blazor webAssembly.
How to assign a value from one MS Blazor's razor page to another razor page after OnClick event. Example:

MainLayout page: Image A, Image B.

NavMenu page: Image C

After click any image (A/B), the image path will assign to Image C in NavMenu page, in order to re-render what has been clicked in MainLayout page. If using JS, I can search the element Id and assign the value to it. But, in MS Blazor, how to do it?

Comment: https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/

Comment: You don't need to say "MS Blazor WebAssembly."  Say "Blazor WASM"